# submit html form programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to submit a form programmatically in android. I don't want any user interaction with a web browser. The user will provide inputs in an EditField and then the inputs will be submitted Through http post method via HTTPwebmethod. But I didn't get any success in the same. Please advise. I have used HTMLUnit in java but its not working in android.

```
  final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.mail.example.com");
     final HtmlForm form = page1.getHtmlElementById("loginform");

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("btrn");
    final HtmlTextInput textField1 = form.getElementById("user");
   final HtmlPasswordInput textField2 =          form.getElementById("password");textField1.setValueAttribute("user.name");
    textField2.setValueAttribute("pass.word"); final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
```

Comment: you're on the right track. what code have you tried, and what error message are you receiving? are you hosting the receiving end as well? can you intercept the request from the emulator, using fiddler tool or wireshark?

Comment: code is posted in original Question but HTTPUnit lib is not converting into dalvik code at compile time. I think it should be executed at server. not in emulator.

Answer (score 11):

Oops. Sorry. Looks like you are trying to POST through the browser afterall.

Here's a snippet I've been using to accomplish HTTP POST's in Android without going through the web browser:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);  
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", "value1"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", "value2")); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name3", "value3"));   
// etc...
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I think that should work for what you're trying to do. I have TIMEOUT_MS set to 10000 (so, 10 seconds)

Then you can read out the server's response using something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()), 8096);
```

Comment: I will do post method but not actually submit the login form. I need to submit already created login page thru code without actually opening the browser.

Comment: It's important to note that the above code needs to be enclosed in a try-catch block and executed from a background thread.

Comment: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient is not supported anymore.